# Save LGBM model in `.cpp` format from Python

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, lightgbm

If I run

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import lightgbm as lgb

breast_cancer = load_breast_cancer()
data = breast_cancer.data
target = breast_cancer.target

params = {
    "task": "convert_model",
    "convert_model_language": "cpp",
    "convert_model": "test.cpp",
}

gbm = lgb.train(params, lgb.Dataset(data, target))
```

then I was expecting that a file called `test.cpp` would be created, with the model saved in c++ format.

However, nothing appears in my current directory.

I have read the documentation (https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#io-parameters), but can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the doc they say:

> Note: can be used only in CLI version

under the *convert_model* and *convert_model_language* parameters.

That means that you should probably use the CLI (Command Line Interfarce) of LGBM instead of the python wrapper to do this.

[Link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quick-Start.html) to Quick Start CLI version.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a bit to get to grips with the CLI version, but I've written out a complete example solution below

Answer (score 5):

Here's a real 'for dummies' answer:

1. Install the CLI version of lightgbm: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html
2. Make note of your installation path, and find the executable. For example, for me, this was `~/LightGBM/lightgbm`.
3. Run the following in a Jupyter notebook:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd

breast_cancer = load_breast_cancer()
data = pd.DataFrame(breast_cancer.data)
target = pd.DataFrame(breast_cancer.target)

pd.concat([target, data], axis=1).to_csv("regression.train", header=False, index=False)

train_conf = """
task = train
objective = binary
metric = auc
data = regression.train
output_model = trained_model.txt
"""

with open("train.conf", "w") as f:
    f.write(train_conf)

conf_convert = """
task = convert_model
input_model= trained_model.txt
"""

with open("convert.conf", "w") as f:
    f.write(conf_convert)
```

```
! ~/LightGBM/lightgbm config=train.conf
```

```
! ~/LightGBM/lightgbm config=convert.conf
```

Your model with be saved in your current directory.

Comment: How do you actually use the result? I can't compile the resulting file. What includes does it need?